# Regression analysis?

Tags: regression, logistic, ordered-logit

I have scored pig carcasses for injuries at 2 points; immediately after slaughter (slaughter stage 1 [SS1]) and again after the carcases have been washed, scalded and dehaired (slaughter stage 2 [SS2]). I have used an ordinal scale to record damage - absent, mild, moderate and severe skin damage. I have reason to believe that mild skin lesions will be less visible at SS2 but severe skin lesions will actually be more visible at SS2. How can I test this? Do I need to do some sort of regression analysis?

Thanks

Comment: Are these the same carcasses at both stages? If so are you able to identify a particular stage 1 carcass at stage 2 (in order to associate their values together)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 3 pieces of information:

Time: ss1 vs. ss2
Type of lesion: Mild vs. Severe
Visibility of lesion: less visible to more visible.

Which of the later 2 variables does your ordinal scale measure? and do you have a measure of the other?

If the ordinal variable is measuring the visibility then you could use proportional odds logistic regression with visibility as the response variable and time and type of lesion, and their interaction as predictor variables.  The interaction term is the main one of interest if you want to show that the visibility changes differently over time for mild vs. severe legions.

Comment: My ordinal scale measures the severity of the lesions. I don't have a direct measure of visibility. When I say visibility I suppose I mean that I want to see if the severity of the lesions is more apparent at one stage than another. For example, is score 3 (severe) assigned more at SS2 than SS1? Is a score of 0 assigned more often at 1 than SS2 etc.

Comment: @GraceCarroll, you might look at McNemar's test if the data is paired (you have the same injury on the same pig at both time periods).